# Chrome 100 is missing the title bar

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, title-bar

Just today, I stopped seeing the title bar for Google Chrome windows.
[image]

I'm quite convinced I saw it in the morning as I always use it to drag my windows between screens. Any idea what setting should I check to change this? I thought there would be a setting for this, but I can't see anything like that:
[image][image]

Any idea how to get my title bar back, please?

- Google Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10 Pro
- Chrome re-install didn't help, and it happens on two different Windows accounts.

Comment: I do not see any difference in what you show here, in my Chrome, which is the same as Edge and has been like that for some revisions. What can you not do?

Comment: @John Thanks for your comment. I can it seems do everything, but I just hate windows not looking as windows, that's it.

Comment: If you tap the alt key (not hold) then *a* title bar may show up.

Comment: I tried that in Chrome 100 and Edge 100 and the Alt key does not produce a title bar. That may have worked a while back but not now.

Comment: That little space between the '+' tab and the downwards facing arrow, you can drag the window around with that.

Comment: @Mokubai That's a Firefox thing.

Comment: If there is only one tab, the tab title can be used to drag the window (but if there are more, dragging the tab title only moves the tab around, or to separate it into another window). Perhaps you confused this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I remember, Chrome never had a title bar.

There was once an option for using the operating system title,
called, appropriately, "Use system title bars and borders",
but Chrome 94 broke it:

[image]

Users then found a workaround, by in `chrome://flags` setting
the option of `use-ozone-platform` to disabled.

However, even this option has now disappeared.
Chrome is now imposing its minimalist display, and there doesn't
currently seem a way to force it.

To display the page title in another way, you could use the open-source
[Show Title Tag extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-title-tag/pkbffbhglicfngmppdlpmpblfgnkdgio/related):

> Shows title in top of the page, since you cant read the title in the
> small tabs. Created by Martin Dalgaard
>
> This plugin will show the full page title in the bottom of the page,
> so you can see the full title. Nice small tool for SEO guys and
> everyone using Chrome.
>
> You can move the bar to each corner so it's never obstructing your
> website. You can also hide it on pages where you don't want it.

[image]

Comment: "called, appropriately, "Use system title bars and borders", but Chrome 94 broke it:"  It still works fine on Chromium 100, Manjaro Linux.

Comment: @AdamBarnes: The option you find is by Linux, not any more by Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "is by Linux"? This option is present on the `chrome://settings/appearance` page, at least in Debian-packaged Chromium 100.0.4896.127. It may be there because Chromium was compiled for a *nix platform, particularly with X11-based desktop (where window manager is a thing). But it's definitely not provided "by Linux".

Comment: @AdamBarnes It used to work everywhere, but after Chrome 94 it’s only available on UNIX-like platforms using X11 (or something directly compatible that utilizes a window manager).

Comment: My opinion is that Chrome hasn't had a title bar for a long time, and that there is no proprietary way to add one. Each browser, it seems, feels the need to make its own standards. If we are going to allow this, then my vote would be to remove the "title" element and tag from HTML. My opinion is that a title bar adds something to the user experience of my websites.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to say bit it's been like that for as long as I can remember. You might be experiencing the "Mandela Effect".

If you have too many tabs open then this area seems to be reserved deadspace for dragging the window.

[image]

---

If anything, there used to be thicker deadspace above the tabs but I seem to recall that upon full-screening the deadspace would be minimal.

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFjK1eapTtI)

Answer (score 5):

I have spent some time looking at both Chrome and Chromium Edge in Windows 10 and 11.

What you see (Tabs with a narrow (very narrow) bar across the top is normal behavior for both Chrome and Edge and has been for several revisions (and even perhaps for a long time).

It is just what we have had and have now.

Answer (score -1):

Closest you can probably get in **Microsoft Edge** is the vertical tab mode, which can be enabled by right clicking on the title bar and selecting 'turn on vertical tabs':

[image]

Comment: I am well aware that Chrome =/= Edge, but as they share 99%... I thought it might be useful for some.

Comment: other browsers like Opera, Vivaldi also have vertical tabs, and they also share the same engine as Chrome

Comment: @phuclv Are you sure about Opera? I can't seem to find it there. Vivaldi I don't have installed.

Comment: [Vivaldi has it built-in](https://vivaldi.com/blog/tab-tricks-vivaldi-browser/) and in Opera there are many extensions to do that https://www.alphr.com/vertical-tab-bars-opera/

Comment: Shew people are hectic with their downvotes - I think this answer is totally valid, cheers.